# android : when i select a picture in gallery app, app is gone

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-gallery, runtimeexception

My app accesses to basic gallery app.

When i select a picture , app is gone with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/9013 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.rusk/com.example.rusk.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/9013 from pid=29852, uid=10097 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

my code is below :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Intent.createChooser"), SELECT_PICTURE);

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult 실행", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
}
   public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add permission in your manifest file like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

as your error says